# Create a new list from a list when a certain condition is met in python

Tags: python, list, append

I want to make a new list of lists when the value in the 3rd column is of the highest 10%.

My list of lists currently look like this:

```
[[1, -1, 10, 0]]
[[2, 1, 20, 5]]
[[3, 2, 15, 10], [4, 2, 85, 10], [5, 2, 90, 10]]
[[6, 3, 75, 11], [7, 4, 78, 11], [8, 5, 80, 11]]
[[9, 6, 13, 14]]
[[10, 7, 50, 17]]
[[11, 8, 70, 30], [12, 8, 95, 30], [13, 8, 90, 30]].....
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
M1 = max(row1)[2]  (maximum value from the 3rd column)

if row1[i][2] >= M1*(0.1):
    newrow1.append()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: also it is not clear what your input is (you mention a list of lists but what you wrote are separate lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[item for item in l if item[2]>10]
```